# Div not floating to right completely

Tags: html, css

Have a social menu that I need to float all the way to the right of my page and stay fixed. However it sort of floats somewhere in between randomly. just looking for a possible fix

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m7vaywmh/

HTML

```
<div class="social_wrap">
    <div class="social">
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=387766698&trk=nav_responsive_tab_profile" target="_blank"><img class="move" src="images/linked.png"/></a>
        <a href="https://www.behance.net/lukerbab3a51" target="_blank"><img class="move" src="images/behance.png"/></a>                 
        <a href="http://factordog.deviantart.com/" target="_blank"><img class="move" src="images/deviant.png"></a>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCMM-HzbbBtU6DhNlUL71rrQ" target="_blank"><img class="move" src="images/yt.png"/></a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/LukebMedia?sk=timeline&app_data" target="_blank"><img class="move" src="images/fb.png"/></a>                       
    </div><!--social -->    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.social_wrap{
    background:#3F3;
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:5001; 
}
.social{
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    width:45%;
    right:0px;
    margin-top:15px;

}
.social img{
    width:5%;
    min-width:15px;
    padding-right:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a hard width on your `.social` class and by default `text-align` is left.

Add `text-align: right` to `.social`

```css
.social_wrap{
    background:#3F3;
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:5001; 
}
.social{
    position:relative;
    float:right;    
    width:45%;
    right:0px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-top:15px;

}
.social img{
    width:5%;
    min-width:15px;
    padding-right:10px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="social_wrap">
        <div class="social">
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=387766698&trk=nav_responsive_tab_profile" target="_blank"><img class="move" src="images/linked.png"/></a>
            <a href="https://www.behance.net/lukerbab3a51" target="_blank"><img class="move" src="images/behance.png"/></a>                 
            <a href="http://factordog.deviantart.com/" target="_blank"><img class="move" src="images/deviant.png"></a>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCMM-HzbbBtU6DhNlUL71rrQ" target="_blank"><img class="move" src="images/yt.png"/></a>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/LukebMedia?sk=timeline&app_data" target="_blank"><img class="move" src="images/fb.png"/></a>                       
        </div><!--social -->    
  </div>
```

Comment: its perfect. just went and did it myself. Thanks for the help there m8. Will amrk as correct answer when it lets me :)

Answer (score 1):

Just change properties of `.social` with following code. Also I share my experience with you. Whenever I have this kind of problems. I try to use border, it helps to see content float.

```
 .social {
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    width:45%;
    right:0px;
    margin-top:15px;
    text-align:right;
    padding-right:15px;

 }
```